# Spring Boot - Filter not applied for noHandlerFoundException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, html-compression

I tried to implement a filter following this answer:

[How do I minify dynamic HTML responses in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423560/how-do-i-minify-dynamic-html-responses-in-spring)

This works very good, however, this filter does not work when the error 404 is thrown. Why not? And how do I apply this filter also for my 404-error page?

**Solution:**

Using the following code:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class NotFoundException {

     @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
     public String noHandlerFoundException() {
          // provide information to view
          return "error";
     }
}
```

with the application.properties:

```
 spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
 spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

allows the redirection to the error page and the filter is applied. However, the warning: "No mapping for GET /css/styles.css" (and all other static resources) is logged. Registering a `ResourceHandler` with:

```
 resourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
 // register resource handler for other static content
```

solved this. See also issues: [#7653](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7653) (spring-boot) and [#29491](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29491) (spring-framework) in the spring-projects, which seem related. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 404 is not a “normal“ exception type error in Spring Boot.

To turn it into a handleable exception add the following to application.properties

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

This may be sufficient to cause the minify filter to be hit.

Otherwise add an [exception handler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_exception_handling.htm#:%7E:text=Exception%20Handler,custom%20responses%20to%20the%20client.&text=Define%20a%20class%20that%20extends%20the%20RuntimeException%20class.&text=You%20can%20define%20the%20%40ExceptionHandler,handle%20the%20exceptions%20as%20shown.) for the not found to apply the `CharResponseWrapper` or other mechanism to provide minified response.

Comment: An example of implementing the exception handler is linked to from my answer. Also look at this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167033/custom-exception-handler-for-nohandlerfoundexception-is-not-working-without-ena

Comment: Look at this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167033/custom-exception-handler-for-nohandlerfoundexception-is-not-working-without-ena

Comment: Use the @ExceptionHandler handleError that has the http response as one of the params. Populate ‘text’ with the text contained in error.html. 
          response.getWriter().write(htmlCompressor.compress(text));

Comment: The fact that static files are not serving is a separate (simpler) issue. Please ask another question and accept my answer - solved your issue with manipulating 404 response.